# how to rename uploaded multiple images so that is not replacing the existing files

Tags: php, image

I have a site where users can upload multiple images i am having problems as the new uploaded files are replacing the existing files in the images directory that has the same name. please help i am new to php

if (isset($_FILES['images'])) 
        {

```
  foreach ($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
        {
                $target = "../uploads/";
                $target = $target.$_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target))
                {
                  $fname=$_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
                  $target = "PostAd/uploads/". $fname;

                mysql_query("INSERT INTO `upload_data`(`clid`, `id`, `Imgpath`,`target`) VALUES ('$clid','$id','$fname','$target')");
                  $target="";
                 }
          }
if ($sql){
     header( "Location: /Myconnec/PostAd/CampusLife/confirm.php?clid=$clid");
     ob_end_flush();
   } else {
     $error_msg = 'ERROR: Problems arose during the information exchange, please try again later.';
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a timestamp like this...

```
if (isset($_FILES['images'])) {

  foreach ($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
        {
                $target = $target.$_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
                $ext = pathinfo($target, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                $rand =  rand();
                $strip_ext = substr($target, 0, strlen($target) - strlen($ext));
                $timestamp =  str_replace(" ","",microtime());
                $target = "$strip_ext.$timestamp.$rand.$ext";
                if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "../upload/$target"))
                {
                  $fname=$_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
                  $target = "PostAd/uploads/".$target;
                  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `upload_data`(`clid`, `id`, `Imgpath`,`target`) VALUES ('$clid','$id','$fname','$target')");
                  $target="";
                 }
          }
if ($sql){
     header( "Location: /Myconnec/PostAd/CampusLife/confirm.php?clid=$clid");
     ob_end_flush();
   } else {
     $error_msg = 'ERROR: Problems arose during the information exchange, please try again later.';
   }
```

Comment: that solved the ext issue when one is .png vs .jpeg but what if both photos have the same ext. such as   .jpeg vs .jpeg what do you do then @dbinns66

Comment: Though I find it highly unlikely that 1) a user would upload 2 different files with the same name in the same batch upload, or 2) that 2 different users would upload files with the same name at the exact same milisecond... ;-) I've added a random number to each timestamped filename...

Comment: its not adding the time stamp nor random # to the image in the database (mysql)

Comment: show the data from the database - and I didnt see you changed  $target after you moved the file... interesting concept...  answer updated...

Comment: my email address is ronald.davis@myconnec.com

Comment: i found something. the code will move the image to the upload folder as 00k0k.0.84656400143119517022544jpg however in the database it is 00k0k.jpeg. so it is not loading the rest of the file ext and random#